# Finding the error term in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This question is inspired from chapter 13 problem 39biii of Spivak's Calculus:

The Schwarz inequality (SI):

$\big[\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \big]^2 \leq \big[\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \big]\cdot \big[\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \big]$

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals (CSI):

$\big[\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\big]^2 \leq \big[\int_a^b [f(x)]^2dx\big]\cdot \big[\int_a^b [g(x)]^2dx\big]$

Problem 39biii) Prove CSI by adapting the proof of SI from problem 2-21 (This will take some imagination).

The proof of SI from problem 2-21 is as follows:

$\big[\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \big]\cdot \big[\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \big] = \big[\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \big]^2 + \sum_{i < j} (x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2 \geq \big[\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \big]^2$

I understand this proof, but I can't see how to generalise it to prove CSI. The general idea behind this proof is to calculate the error term of SI, which is that $\sum_{i < j} (x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2$ term. So my only idea is to calculate the error term of CSI, which (unsimplified) would be:

$E = \big[\int_a^b [f(x)]^2dx\big]\cdot \big[\int_a^b [g(x)]^2dx\big] - \big[\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\big]^2$

But I can't see how to simplify $E$ into a form (I'm guessing a sum of positive integrals?) which is clearly positive. Or maybe Spivak had another approach in mind?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Write$$\begin{align}E&=\int_a^bf^2(x)dx\int_a^bg^2(y)dy-\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\int_a^bf(y)g(y)dy\\&=\int_{[a,\,b]^2}(f^2(x)g^2(y)-f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y))dxdy\\&=\int_{a\le x\le y\le b}(f^2(x)g^2(y)+f^2(y)g^2(x)-2f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y))dxdy\\&=\int_{a\le x\le y\le b}(f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y))^2dxdy.\end{align}$$

Comment: @SenZen Whatever Spivak expects, that's the only way you can write $E$ in the form you need. It's only the integrals equivalent of what you do with sums, viz.$$\sum_ix_i^2\sum_jy_j^2-\sum_ix_iy_i\sum_jx_jy_j=\sum_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2.$$

Comment: I don't get it. For example, what does $\int_{[a,b]^2} 1 dx dy$ mean?

Comment: And also what does $\int_{a \leq x \leq y \leq b} 1 dx dy$ mean?

Comment: @SenZen For any $S\subseteq\Bbb R^2$, $\int_Sdxdy$ is the area of $S$.

Comment: I had to look this up. So $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the 2 dimensional plane of real numbers? Spivak hasn't even mentioned the concept of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so far...

Comment: If I choose $S = \{ (x, x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ (in other words a straight diagonal line), what is the "area of this $S$"? I guess $0$?

Comment: What about $S = \{ (~\cos(t), \sin(t)~): t \in \mathbb{R} \} $ (this is the edge of a circle). Is this area $0$? Or is it the area enclosed by the circle?

Comment: If this solution is what Spivak expects us to imagine up - I'm surprised that I'm surprised.

Comment: @SenZen Those examples have area $0$, but they're unsuitable as ranges for double integrals anyway. The regions I'm using are either squares or triangles.

Comment: @SenZen: You can write it as the iterated integral $\int_a^b \int_a^y (f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y))^2 \, dx \, dy$ if you understand that better. It is also equal to $\frac 12 \int_a^b \int_a^b (f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y))^2 \, dx \, dy$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes I can understand those better, but how do you derive them?